# Multiple datasources annotated with Qualifiers always return the wrong datasource

Tags: java, datasource, cdi, wildfly

I am using old-school datasource activities - no JPA involved at all. So no `persistence.xml` or `EntityManager`.

I have a CDI producer as follows:

```
@Dependent
public class JdbcAdapterProviderProducer {

  @Resource(name = "jboss/datasources/DS1")
  @ConnectionPool(DS1)
  private DataSource ds1DataSource;

  @Resource(name = "jboss/datasources/DS2")
  @ConnectionPool(DS2)
  private DataSource ds2DataSource;

  @Produces @ConnectionPool(DS1)
  public JdbcAdapterProvider getDs1JdbcAdapterProvider() {
    return new JdbcAdapterProvider(ds1DataSource);
  }

  @Produces @ConnectionPool(DS2)
  public JdbcAdapterProvider getDs2JdbcAdapterProvider() {
    return new JdbcAdapterProvider(ds2DataSource);
  }
}
```

Which I then leverage by injecting like so:

```
@Inject @ConnectionPool(DS2)
private JdbcApdapterProvider jdbcAdapterProvider;
```

The problem is that the datasource that is getting injected isn't either of the ones I am trying to access. Specifically, it's always the `jboss/datasources/ExampleDS` datasource.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't you use mappedName instead of name in @Resource?

Comment: @XavierDury I was under the impression from the documentation that I could use `name` in that form. However, changing it to `mappedName` indeed did the trick. However `mappedName` isn't portable - what would be the portable way to do Resource Injection in this case?

Comment: `lookup` seems to work as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're getting mixed up with `name` vs `lookup` in your @Resource annotations:

**name:** defines the name of the resource reference, making it available (this as a "destination")
**lookup:** defines what to plug the resource reference into (think of this as the "source")

According to the Java EE 7 spec, a DataSource with no lookup will give you "java:comp/DefaultDataSource", so when you define an annotation like:

```
@Resource(name = "jboss/datasources/DS2")
@ConnectionPool(DS2)
private DataSource ds2DataSource;
```

This gets interpreted as:

```
@Resource(name = "jboss/datasources/DS2", lookup = "java:comp/DefaultDataSource")
@ConnectionPool(DS2)
private DataSource ds2DataSource;
```

which explains why you are getting `jboss/datasources/ExampleDS` back, because that datasource is probably what you get from looking `java:comp/DefaultDataSource`.

Comment: >"getting mixed up with name vs lookup" - This is a very common confusion and indicative of the fact that `@Resource` is not such a well designed annotation (it's too much overloaded).

Comment: Agreed, although it's the entire resource reference mechanism which is confusing to most (not just the annotation). The annotation is consistent with how a resource ref can be defined in xml.